# Publish data without ROS

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey,

As I found out, Gazebo has it's own Gazebo messages for intern communication.
To communicate with outside of the simulation there is always the opportunity to use ROS messages (conversion included into ros_gazebo_pkgs)

I'm interested if there is also another way to, f.e. publish data, into the non gazebo world. Without the usage of ROS?

Greetings!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26453/publish-data-without-ros/) by [morrac](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36133/morrac/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 57 on 2021-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use ignition-transport and write C++ code to publish/subscribe without using ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2021-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2